# Maintenance to Resourcepool in Anylogic

Tags: java, anylogic

in my model i have a resource with a capacity higher then one, among other resources and seize & release blocks.
after the resources is used higher the x times i want to disable it for maintenance.
i release the resource near the end of the process and that is my preferred time for the maintenance call.
i have several questions:

- do i need to identify the specific resource used from the resourcepool? if yes' than how do i
  do that?
- hope do i disable the resource it won't be used for a specific time?
- what is the correct way to count the number of times the specific resource is used?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple example of how you can achieve this.

First off you will need a custom resource type with a variable to count the number of times that you use the resource

[image]

You will also need a downtime block where you can specify the maintenance that the resource will be taken.

Then in the "On Seize" Code of the Resource Pool you can increase the `timesUsed` variable inside the resource agent, and in the "On Release" you can specify the maintenance to start if the `timesUsed` is greater than your limit, just remember to reset it as well, `unit.timesUsed = 0;`.

[image]

Comment: hi, thanke for your answer, i did what you suggested and i got the error: "type mismatch: cannot convert from int to boolean", i defended the variable as int' why do i get this error?

Comment: You will need to provide more details - where exactly did you get the error? Possible add the location either as screenshot or as text. My example is self-contained and can be replicated and run. Maybe try replicating my example before implementing it in yours.